# Progress Dialog, Broadcast receiver crash in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver, progressdialog

I have been trying for a long time to work on a button onClick listener that performs the following

- launch a loading screen (progress bar).
- Send an sms msg in the background to a specific number.
- wait for the reply using broadcast listener, which is a message containing a link.
- dismiss the loading screen.
- then take this link and use it to start another activity.

The code shows no errors, however each time I press the button it doesn't show the progress bar, it only sends a message then waits for the specified time then crashes.
Here's the code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                `public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new LoadTracker().execute();
                }});
}


protected void sendSMS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Phoneno = "***********";
    String Message = "www.google.com";
    SmsManager manager= SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(Phoneno, null, Message, null, null);
}

    private BroadcastReceiver Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
         public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
            if (intentExtras != null) {
                Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);

                for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                   Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(smsBody));
                    startActivity(in);
                }
        }
 }};

private class LoadTracker extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);  
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Sending Signal"); 
        progressDialog.setMessage("Receiving Signal, Please Wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);  
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();  
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            synchronized (this){
                IntentFilter IF = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");


                sendSMS();
                registerReceiver(Receiver,IF);

                this.wait(10000);

                this.wait(10000);

                publishProgress(100); 
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
            progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]); 
        }

     @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
        {  
            //close the progress dialog  
            progressDialog.dismiss();  
            //initialize the View  
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(Receiver);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Note: The Phone number belongs to the phone on which the application is running so it should open google after it receives the reply

All the uses permissions are in place too.

Update: I discovered the problem with the progress dialog, the "O" letter in OnPreExecute Should've been lower case. Now the progress Dialog appears and the app sends the message however, the app crashes as soon as the reply sms message is received. How can I solve this?

Logcat:

```
04-20 19:45:45.950: W/dalvikvm(15877): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4b1f8)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.finalprototype.MainActivity$1@4162c988
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:741)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.google.com }
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1535)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1387)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.example.finalprototype.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:75)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:732)
04-20 19:45:45.974: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    ... 9 more
04-20 19:45:56.013: I/Process(15877): Sending signal. PID: 15877 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Where do you call progressDialog#show()? Do you have a logcat for the crash?

Comment: Its called in the onPreExecute(), for some reason its not showing in the code above

Comment: update your code and post the logcat please

Comment: Done, i apologize if it seems all over the place i am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but from the following line

```
ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.google.com ...
```

I think your URL should be like `http://www.google.com`. Its missing the protocol `http` without which it might not recognize the right activity to handle the `Intent`.